# In Lotus Notes Designer Trigger an Agent, every time an email message is opened

Tags: triggers, lotus-notes, lotus, agent

New to Lotus Notes Admin, Brand new to designer.

Looking to trigger an agent whenever an email is opened.

I've created the agent already, just don't know how to hook it to the action of opening up an email.

Feel stupid opening up a PMR just for that, but have been googling and experimenting for hours.

thanks for any help

Comment: Where do you want the agent to run? If you want it to run in the Notes client of the person who opened the email message, than Karl-Henry's answer is correct - but you can't assume that that client is connected to any network resources at the time that the agent runs! If you want the agent to run on the server, there are ways to do it -- but you won't actually be able to tell whether the email was opened (and seen) by a user or by code -- for example by the replicator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the mail template (which is not recommended unless you know what you are doing).
The code could go in either the QueryOpen or PostOpen event of the memo form and reply form.
My suggestion is to isolate the functionality in a script library and call that function from the events on the different forms. This will make it easier both to update/maintain the code as well as move it to the new mail template when Notes get updated.

For something like this, I would recommend that you contact an experienced Notes developer for some help. You could easily mess up the mail template.